# Flowplayer f4m stream starts at the begining

Tags: http-live-streaming, flowplayer

i'm using flowplayer for http livestreaming, the trouble comes when the streaming is playing from the beggining and not from the live. I don't know if there is anything wrong in the code or if there are any parameters missing.

Help please!

```
<script language="JavaScript">
flowplayer('player', 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf', {
    clip: {
        // the manifest file
        url: '(httpurl).f4m',
        ipadUrl: '(httpurl).m3u8',
        // we need 2 urlResolvers
        urlResolvers: ['f4m','bwcheck'],




        // use the httpstreaming plugin
        provider: 'httpstreaming',

        // directory where the manifest and video fragments are stored
        baseUrl: 'http://stream.flowplayer.org/httpstreaming/',
        live: true,
        autoPlay: true
    },
    plugins: {
        f4m: {
            url: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.f4m-3.2.9.swf',

        },
        httpstreaming: {
            url: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.httpstreaming-3.2.10.swf',
        startLivePosition: true
        },
        controls: {
            // the 'tube' skin
            url: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.controls-tube-3.2.15.swf'
        },

        bwcheck: {
            url: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.bwcheck-httpstreaming-3.2.12.swf',
            dynamic: true,
            // show the selected file in the content box
            // usually omitted in production
            onStreamSwitchBegin: function (newItem, currentItem) {
                var content = $f('httpstreaming-dynamic').getPlugin('content');
                var message = 'Will switch to: ' +
                               newItem.streamName +
                                ' from ' +
                                currentItem.streamName;
                content.setHtml(message);
            },
            onStreamSwitch: function (newItem) {
                var content = $f('httpstreaming-dynamic').getPlugin('content');
                var message = 'Switched to: ' + newItem.streamName;
                content.setHtml(message);
            }
        },

        // a content box to display the selected bitrate
        // usually omitted in production
        content: {
            url: 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.content-3.2.8.swf',
            bottom: 30,
            left: 0,
            width: 400,
            height: 150,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            backgroundGradient: 'none',
            border: 0,
            textDecoration: 'outline',
            style: {
                body: {
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'Arial',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    color: '#ffffff'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).ipad();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place a directive of "start: -1" in your clip conifguration.

Worked for me!

```
clip {
...
    // directory where the manifest and video fragments are stored
    baseUrl: 'http://stream.flowplayer.org/httpstreaming/',
    live: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    start: -1
},
```